# Analyze callstack

Tags: debugging, callstack, crash-dumps

When an exception occurs I get the callstack

```
if(!GetModuleFileNameA((HMODULE) hMod, szModule, len))
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

szModule is

```
RtlTryEnterCriticalSection+0x0000000000000052
RtlTimeFieldsToTime+0x00000000000002E0
free+0x000000000000001C
...
```

1. What does the Hex number next to the name of the function mean?

   > ```
   > 0x0000000000000052 
   > 0x00000000000002E0
   > 0x000000000000001C
   > ```
2. What problem could bring up a callstack like that?

Comment: The number typically means an offset in bytes from the address of the beginning of the function. You'd have to refer to a disassembly of the function to find the actual instruction in question.

Comment: I'd propose to use a debugger rather than trying to do your own exception analysis within your program. Regarding the problem, it's more relevant to have the exception code than the callstack. The exception code says _why_ it has crashed. The callstack says _where_ it has crashed.